# Updating outlets after dismissing a viewController

Tags: ios, swift, dismiss

First of all let me explain what exactly is the scenario I want to archive.

My rootviewcontroller -> FirstViewController -> DetailViewController -> Detail2ViewController and then back to FirstViewController with a label updated by a function inside FirstViewController.

(Assume that -> means a press of a button)

Now I use this to call the function from the last viewController:

```
var go = FirstViewController()

self.go.get() //get is the function that updates the textfield text.

self.presentingViewController?.presentingViewController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

Now I print the string I wanted to be the new text of my label and it works but when I use this line:

```
self.label.text = newone // newone is the new string
```

I have a crash with this log:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Of course the same function is working when I first reach the FirstViewController and I also tried to use a string to insert to the label text like this:

```
self.label.text = "hello"
```

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

I forgot to put navigation controllers.

NavContr -> rootviewcontroller -> FirstViewController -> DetailViewController -> NavContr ->Detail2ViewController

Comment: As the answer below said, `var go = FirstViewController()` is wrong, you have to use something like `let go = self.presentingViewController!.presentingViewController! as! FirstViewController ` (also not recommended, use delegate instead)

Comment: @Tj3n thanks for your comment I have tried to do it with delegates but I couldn't I edited my question with nav controllers can you give me an example with the new scenario?

Answer (score 1):

`var go = FirstViewController()`.
Everytime this will create a new instance of `FirstViewController()` and will not use your already initialized instance of `viewController`. Reportedly the **label** will be **nil** hence you are getting `fatal error`.
Try by getting your already initialized object from stack(if you are using it and there is one).

Comment: Thanks for the answer can you give me an example ?